# Can't get real IP client nginx reverse proxy

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a laravel website, where on my website there is a feature to get IP address for clients that open my website.

But when I use nginx for reverse proxy, on my website what is read is the Nginx server IP, not the client IP.

I already added :

```
proxy_set_header Host $ host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $ remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $ proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

And this my nginx configuration :

```
upstream my.site {
    server 192.168.1.5:30111;
    server 192.168.1.4:30111;
    server 192.168.1.3:30111 backup;
    server 192.168.1.2:30111 backup;
}

server {
    server_name my.site;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my.site;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Still not working.

Please help me.

Comment: You need to configure your trusted proxies. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Comment: it's work. thanks for your answer @ceejayoz